# Wrong package version between disto and archive

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager

Some packages known to apt-get have different versions than what is found in the archive.  For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-system-x86
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 cpu-checker ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms msr-tools ovmf qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui seabios
Suggested packages:
 samba vde2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 cpu-checker ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms msr-tools ovmf qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 seabios
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 228 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 51.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 msr-tools amd64 1.3-3 [10.0 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 cpu-checker amd64 0.7-1.1 [6,936 B]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ipxe-qemu all 1.0.0+git-20190109.133f4c4-0ubuntu3.2 [930 kB]
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms all 1.0.0+git-20150424.a25a16d-0ubuntu4 [552 kB]
Ign:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-common amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Ign:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-data all 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Ign:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-gui amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 seabios all 1.13.0-1ubuntu1.1 [138 kB]
Ign:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-x86 amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ovmf all 0~20191122.bd85bf54-2ubuntu3.3 [2,490 kB]
Ign:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-data all 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-common amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-gui amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-x86 amd64 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-data all 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 qemu-system-data all 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21
 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Fetched 4,127 kB in 2s (2,089 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-common_4.2-3ubuntu6.21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-data_4.2-3ubuntu6.21_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-gui_4.2-3ubuntu6.21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-x86_4.2-3ubuntu6.21_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

One of the package the tool is trying to fetch is:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-common_4.2-3ubuntu6.21_amd64.deb
```

but the file that exists is:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-common_4.2-3ubuntu6.24_amd64.deb
```

So there is a discrepancy between what apt-get wants and what is available in the archive.  I have tried running "apt-get update" or "apt-get --fix-missing" as suggested to no avail.

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update your software lists; your issue shows a user-level or *procedural* error.  I picked a package at random in your paste & the package available is

```
 qemu-system-common | 1:4.2-3ubuntu6          | focal            | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 qemu-system-common | 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.24       | focal-security   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 qemu-system-common | 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.24       | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 qemu-system-common | 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.25       | focal-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

but your system with it's outdated lists is looking for `1:4.2-3ubuntu6.21`

Your issue is the lack of security fixes & updates & system being very outdated.

A full-upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system will report as [Ubuntu 20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) but yours is reporting as 20.04.2 ? as you've not applied security fixes or updates since before [August 2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/).

*Please note the ISO release date links I provided are for new installs, installed systems received these updates a week+ before the ISO release date.*

Use
`sudo apt update` to update your software lists
`sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply fixes

I hope your system is kept offline.

Comment: That is the problem, I want to do an upgrade but apt can't find the right version for many packages.You are referencing "software lists" in your reply - where are those and how do I upgrade them?

Comment: As stated in the answer, "*Use `sudo apt update` to update your software lists*" ... ie. that downloads the software lists of what packages are available... then you use `sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply the upgraded fixes discovered in your updated software lists.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?   or a 3rd party respin of Ubuntu (*such as that created by Nvidia for use with Jetson boards etc.. which aren't Ubuntu, but partially Ubuntu based products with packages from Debian too which can cause updated Ubuntu packages from failing to install*).  If you're using a 3rd party OS such as that from Nvidia, you need to get support from your OS elsewhere as due to non-Ubuntu you system differs to Ubuntu in many ways we don't allow for.

Comment: I have tried running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` but always getting packages with the wrong version, i.e:

Comment: `E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Read the messages of `sudo apt update`; are there any warnings?  any errors?  Are all lines appearing without any missed lines?   Your description implies problems with this step, but we cannot see the messages, nor view your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file which is the *primary* file which controls where packages come from. Your problem is also possibly a prior error you've not yet fixed (`sudo apt -f install`) and message you ignored that has put a *hold* on package updates until you correct prior problem; but we only see messages you paste for us.

Comment: Here is a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rMJnYNxhRP/) of the output for "sudo apt update".  There are issues with arm64 links but those are not even in "/etc/apt/sources.list".  I'm not sure how that can be happening.

Comment: What is your architecture?   Your *pastebin* contains an invalid list of sources for incompatible architectures, which could create problems. Your question details match an *amd64* system, yet your paste also shows *arm64* (port) ??  Whilst most packages between architectures will align perfectly; there are cases where they do not, but as hardware is single architecture (or compatible architectures; eg. *amd64* + *i386*, *arm64* + *armhf*) it doesn't create problems unless users unwisely mix incompatible architectures, which you appear to have done.